# Intercept kafka consumer just after processing of records in the last poll completes

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Kafka consumer interceptor interface  (shown below)  has the methods   `onConsume` which is triggered when the records are about to be returned to the consumer, and `onCommit` which is triggered  after the  offsets get committed

```
public interface ConsumerInterceptor<K, V> extends Configurable {
    public ConsumerRecords<K, V> onConsume(ConsumerRecords<K, V> records);
    public void onCommit(Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets);
    public void close();
}
```

My question is whether there is  a way to intercept the consumer just after the poll loop has completed processing the records (returned in the poll). Note that `onCommit` won't do the job since the consumer might be configured with autocommit enabled,  and it is triggered after the commit request sent to the server has been acknowledged.